# How add a default parameter in mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In a file .htaccess I use a following rule:

```
# enable URI rewrite
RewriteEngine On

# if request is for an actual file or directory on disk,
# then do not continue with rewrite engine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?/? index.php?to=prepared&section=$1&category=$2&orderby=$3&filter=$4 [L,QSA]
```

How to make a rule for a case when POST query "orderby" empty and I wish to assign by default to it some value, for example, "rating"?

I want to add a default "orderby" parameter if there is no "orderby" at all!

Thank you very much!

Comment: is there any reason you want to handle this inside `.htaccess`? Since it's fairly simple to set this default value in your `index.php` if `$_GET['orderby']` doesn't contain a value, that might be the easiest solution

Comment: I want to find solution and to handle this inside .htaccess. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to let PHP handle the missing value, i.e. assign a default. Rewrite rules as used in .htaccess work on fixed regular expressions and do not allow for handling logic the way programming languages do.

For the pattern to match correctly, the third capture group in the "pretty" URL needs to have an `orderby` value in the original query string. `[^/]+` explicity requires at least one character (that is not a slash).

You can omit the non-capturing group `(?:/([^/]+))?` near the end.

This will work, making the 4th group (filter) optional:

```
^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?
```

Comment: Thanks. In my rule the 4th group (filter) can stay out.